# How to generate Public and Private Key Pair?

Tags: php, encryption-asymmetric

I have read all about asymmetric encryption in PHP. I understand the mcrypt method. I understand the requirement of having two keys (Public and Private). The only thing I could not understand that where and how I generate these key pairs? Can anyone please explain the process of key generation?
Thank You!

Comment: Where specifically have you read *all about asymmetric encryption* with *mcrypt*? It [only spports symetric](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649672/does-mcrypt-support-asymmetric-encryption) ciphers.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that mcrypt requires two keys. I meant that I have read about both symmetric n asymmetric encryption. I have edited the question.

Comment: Look around [`openssl_pkey_new`](http://php.net/openssl_pkey_new), or use the command line `openssl` tool to generate a key pair.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need [a PGP library](https://github.com/singpolyma/openpgp-php) to do what you wish, but it's pretty straightforward. To create your keys, use:

```
<?php

require dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/openpgp.php';
require dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/openpgp_crypt_rsa.php';

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$k = $rsa->createKey(512);
$rsa->loadKey($k['privatekey']);

$nkey = new OpenPGP_SecretKeyPacket(array(
   'n' => $rsa->modulus->toBytes(),
   'e' => $rsa->publicExponent->toBytes(),
   'd' => $rsa->exponent->toBytes(),
   'p' => $rsa->primes[1]->toBytes(),
   'q' => $rsa->primes[2]->toBytes(),
   'u' => $rsa->coefficients[2]->toBytes()
));

$uid = new OpenPGP_UserIDPacket('Test <test@example.com>');

$wkey = new OpenPGP_Crypt_RSA($nkey);
$m = $wkey->sign_key_userid(array($nkey, $uid));

print $m->to_bytes();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Further question though, do I need to download library files(openpgp.php & openpgp_crypt_rsa.php) from somewhere? Because the code is giving below error for these lines : Failed opening required '/home/content/27/11042427/html/../lib/openpgp.php

Comment: You'll need to install the requisite PHP files from [here](https://github.com/singpolyma/openpgp-php). Again, best of luck and leave a question if you've further issues