# encryption and decryption does not work in php

Tags: php

Reciever:

```
$secureRandom = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32, $strong);
$private = curve25519_private($secureRandom);
$public = curve25519_public($private);
```

the reciever sends $public to the sender.

The sender encrypt the message 'Hello'

```
$x = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $public, 'Hallo', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, 9999)
```

and send the encrypted message to the reciever.

the reciever can now decrypt the message with his private key

```
$result = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $private, DECRYPTED_MESSAGE, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, 9999);
```

i await that $result has 'Hallo' but that do not work at me.

can you help?

Comment: what's your php version and does there any errors ?

Comment: shouldn't `DECRYPTED_MESSAGE` be just `$x`?

Comment: phpinfo says: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21

Comment: there are no errors, the result from mcrypt_encrypt is ,ÛíB­q4¬&ð¶Y» and that is right because the message is encrypted, but the result from mcrypt_decrypt is ;ô"©èeß2$:¸d| also encrypted, i await Hallo

Comment: [Mcrypt doesn't support public key encryption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649672/does-mcrypt-support-asymmetric-encryption). You're encrypting with a symmetric cypher using one key and decrypting it with a different key.

You're already on the right track using `openssl` functions but you're only using it to generate your key, look at [openssl_public_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php) and openssl_public_decrypt functions.

Comment: i have learned that one encrypt a message with the public key von reciever, the reciever gets the encrypted message and decrypt it with his private key, therefor two different keys. or is that not right?